# The Destination Server is Currently Rejecting replication Request - Error Event ID1864. Warning ID 2092

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, replication

hope some one can help me with the subject mentioned error.

My current set is that  I have physical Win2k8R2 Box and a Virtual server with the same configuration.

recently I am having replication error with Event ID 1864 and Warning Event ID 2092.  When I do "repadmin /showrepl" I get the Following errors.

Repadmin: running command /showrepl against full DC localhost

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC02

DSA Options: IS_GC DISABLE_INBOUND_REPL DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL

Site Options: (none)

DSA object GUID: fbd8fb1d-1020-465c-8528-3b55af490202

DSA invocationID: 5b746b00-424e-4243-82bc-a35fd38ec672

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=Miracle-Adventure,DC=Com

```
Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0c073222-6d5a-4389-bc07-32b3f4069ac4

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    125 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:53:20.

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0ff61eba-7e82-401c-b784-6478146122a3

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    126 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 15:49:36.
```

CN=Configuration,DC=Miracle-Adventure,DC=Com

```
Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0ff61eba-7e82-401c-b784-6478146122a3

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    126 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:49:53.

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0c073222-6d5a-4389-bc07-32b3f4069ac4

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    127 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:49:53.
```

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Miracle-Adventure,DC=Com

```
Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0c073222-6d5a-4389-bc07-32b3f4069ac4

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    127 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:49:53.

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0ff61eba-7e82-401c-b784-6478146122a3

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    127 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:49:53.
```

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=Miracle-Adventure,DC=Com

```
Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0c073222-6d5a-4389-bc07-32b3f4069ac4

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    127 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 10:03:19.

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0ff61eba-7e82-401c-b784-6478146122a3

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    126 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 15:48:03.
```

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=Miracle-Adventure,DC=Com

```
Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0c073222-6d5a-4389-bc07-32b3f4069ac4

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    127 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 09:49:53.

Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01 via RPC

    DSA object GUID: 0ff61eba-7e82-401c-b784-6478146122a3

    Last attempt @ 2014-08-04 11:48:51 failed, result 8457 (0x2109):

        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

    126 consecutive failure(s).

    Last success @ 2014-06-29 15:52:04.
```

Source: Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC03

******* 127 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2014-06-29 10:03:19

Last error: 8457 (0x2109):

```
        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.
```

Source: Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC01

******* 127 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2014-06-29 15:52:04

Last error: 8457 (0x2109):

```
        The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.
```

---

when I run DCDIAG /test:DNS I ahve no error

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:

Trying to find home server...

Home Server = MIRACLEDC02

- Identified AD Forest. 
  Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC02

```
  Starting test: Connectivity

     ......................... MIRACLEDC02 passed test Connectivity
```

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\MIRACLEDC02

```
  Starting test: DNS



     DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...

     ......................... MIRACLEDC02 passed test DNS
```

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

Running partition tests on : Schema

Running partition tests on : Configuration

Running partition tests on : Miracle-Adventure

Running enterprise tests on : Miracle-Adventure.Com

```
  Starting test: DNS

     ......................... Miracle-Adventure.Com passed test DNS
```

I have already run the following but it did not solve the problem

repadmin / options miracledc02 -disable_inbound_repl

repadmin / options miracledc02 -disable_outbound_repl

Thank you for your valuable inputs in this regards.....